# can we say "he is lying sideways on the bed"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I think this girl is sitting sideways on the chair.

[image: girl sitting with her legs over one arm of a chair]

I often say to my children "**are you sitting sideways on the chair?**" like picture 1 and then they invented this "**he is lying sideways on the bed**" when they saw this picture

[image: Stick figure lying on a bed parallel to the headboard]

Can we say "**he is lying sideways on the bed**" as shown in the picture 2?

Comment: Must be a big bed or a small person.

Comment: [According to the band Phish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sbh8b45WN5A) (around 0:22) you can at least sleep "lengthwise" and "diagonal[ly]" in your bed. By that measure, "sideways" seems consistent.

Comment: One might also say that girl is sitting [sidesaddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidesaddle).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have never heard sidesaddle used to reference this sitting position. The photo on the wiki page shows there is not much commonality between the two postures. Where have you encountered this usage?

Comment: @Jontia I seem to recall it used (some what figuratively) for someone sitting at an angle significantly different from the "intended." But, as I search for example now, I'm coming up short.  If someone described that position that way, I don't think I'd find it all that strange, but I guess it's not common, either. Maybe I dreamed it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely refer to this as lying sideways on the bed. I actually use this phrase on a regular basis when my children get themselves into an odd position in their beds.

To be clearer you might wish to say "lying sideways **across** the bed". The use of across reinforces the idea that it is the position relative to the bed.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I would actually find "sideways across the bed" *less* clear than "sideways on the bed".  The latter is so natural and clear (and familiar) to me that I would wonder whether the "across" was meant to convey something extra or different.

Answer (score 3):

I mean, it’s technically true. The problem is just that it’s a rather unusual sitting/lying position, so people would probably default to thinking you mean something else. Like lying on the bed, not on your front or back, but with the weight on the edges of your body:

So something like this:

[image]

Which, according to a Google search for that sentence, is to be the more common position.

So if you want to use it like that you probably need to add more context explaining that you mean the less common lying position and what that looks like.

Comment: I'd refer to this a "laying on their side" rather than sideways.

Comment: @Jontia: Only birds lay. We lie.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian good point.

Comment: @Jontia - in standard English, it would be lying on their side.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian  In that case, I am puzzled how we fail to tell the truth on the bed.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Psychoanalysis is mired in uncertainty.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks for the edit; I'm not sure which part of it is automated, but the edit introduced a grammatical error in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

On the bed we may lie [crosswise](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crosswise) or [crossways](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crossways). Normally we lie [lengthways](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lengthways) or [lengthwise](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lengthwise).

On a chair we may sit [sideways](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sideways) ("*To, towards, or from the side*").

The *normal* use of a chair is so well established that we no longer need a word to describe it(!), though parents and teachers might tell kids to *sit up properly* or to *sit up straight* or to *face the front*.